# Load a variable with jQuery into a div based on radio button choice

Tags: jquery, variables, radio-button, load, loading

**Problem:**

Loading a variable into a div based on choice of radio button.

**HTML code:**

```
//Variable to be loaded into
<div id="choice"></div>

//Available variables
$choice1 = '<div id="choice-1">Choice 1</div>';
$choice2 = '<div id="choice-2">Choice 2</div>';

//Radio buttons
<input type="radio" name="authors" id="authors" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="authors" id="authors" value="2">
```

**jQuery code (so far):**

```
$("input[name='authors']").change(function() 
{    
    $('div[id=choice]').load();   
});
```

**Scenario:**

If a user choose first radio button (value=1) then $choice1 should be loaded into . If second radio button is chosen after that, $choice1 should be removed and replaced with $choice2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get those variables from a PHP script. In that case, send a parameter with the load request, like

```
$(”#choice”).load('myscript.php?choice=' + choice); // choice is variable in which you should put 1 or 2
```

And in the PHP:

```
if($GET['choice'] == 1) echo $choice1;
else if($GET['choice'] == 2) echo $choice2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var choiceArray = ['choice one', 'choice two'];
$("input[name='authors']").change(function() 
{    
    $('#choice').html(choiceArray[parseInt($(this).val())]);   
});
```

Also note that arrays start their indexing at 0, so you'd also have to start your radio button values at 0, or use their `index()`.

Comment: This only loads the strings into the div, but I would like that it takes in the PHP variables $choice1 and $choice2 instead.

Comment: `var choiceArray = [$choice1, $choice2]`

Comment: only if they are available in the PHP script that builds this page.

Comment: Is it really possible to combine PHP variables with jQuery this way? Because I can't get it to work.

Comment: no, you're going to have to echo the php vars into a script var.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='authors']").change(function() 
{    
    if(this.value == 1 ) {
      $('#choice').empty().append($choice1);
      // or
      // $('#choice').html($choice1);
    } else {
      $('#choice').empty().append($choice2);   
      // or
      // $('#choice').html($choice1);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duC9n/3/)**

Comment: Not really related, but why did you use .empty().append()? .html() is shorter, and achieves the same result, I thought?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='authors']").change(function() 
{    
    if(this.value== 1 )
    {
      $('#choice').remove($choice2);  
      $('#choice').add($choice1);  

    } 
    else
    {
      $('#choice').remove($choice1);
      $('#choice').add($choice2);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your HTML Code the js is as follow

```
$("input[name='authors']").click(function() {
    var choice = '';
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
if (value == 1) {
    choice += '<div id="choice-1">Choice 1</div>';
}
else {
    choice += '<div id="choice-1">Choice 2</div>';
}
$('#choice').html(choice);
});
```

A Demo is here:
 http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/Ww9yw/4/